# How can I get document information in two collections?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-helper

I have two collections, a collection has images of cars (Uploads), other collection has car information (Cars), colleciton car's id is the same with `carid` (Uploads colleciton). I need to do that to show table cars with their picture.

Here is my code:

```
Template.Araclar.helpers({
  manset: function() {
    getData = Cars.find({});
    return Cars.find({});
    Uploads.find({
      "carid": getData._id
    });
  }
});

<div class="row">
    {{#each manset}}
    <div>{{aracmarka}}</div>
    <div style="width:400px; height:200px;" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb m-t-30">
        <a>
            <img class="img-responsive" style="height:200px;" src="{{url}}" alt="">
        </a>
    </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Note: `{{aracmarka}}` gets from Cars collection `{{url}}` gets from Uploads collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the data context in a template helper through the `this` keyword, for example:

```
Template.Araclar.helpers({
    cars: function() {
        return Cars.find({});
    },
    url: function() {
        var upload = Uploads.findOne({
            "carid": this._id
        });
        return upload && upload.url;
    }
});
```

---

```
<div class="row">
    {{#each cars}}
        <div>{{aracmarka}}</div>
        <div style="width:400px; height:200px;" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6 thumb m-t-30">
            <a>
                <img class="img-responsive" style="height:200px;" src="{{url}}" alt="" />
            </a>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```